# Hours not being added to date object in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 to insert values from a csv file into a postgres database. I need to increment my starting time by 6 hours each time I read a new line from my csv file. I am trying to accomplish this with the following:

```
date_product_str = '2015-03-05 12:00:00'
date_product = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_product_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00").date()

date_valid = date_product
interval = datetime.timedelta(hours=6)

id_location=38
in_file = open("inform_values.csv", "r")


while True:
        line = in_file.readline()
        if not line: break
        tokens = line.split(",")
        for i in range (1, 140):
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO inform_tseries_data_basin_proc_fcst_prob_flow (date_product, date_valid, id_location, id_member, value) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (date_product, date_valid, id_location, i, tokens[i]))
                date_valid = date_valid + interval
                print date_valid
                conn.commit()


cur.close()
conn.close()
```

but this just prints out 2015-03-05 at each step. When I made my interval equal to 1 day:

```
interval = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

it increments one day at a time as expected. Why is it not working for hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `date` object has no concept of hours, minutes, seconds, or microseconds - only year, month, and day.  In `date + timedelta` arithmetic - as the docs say - "`timedelta.seconds` and `timedelta.microseconds` are ignored."

If you need to account for hours, you need a `datetime` object instead.  Which you would have if you removed the trailing `.date()` extractor from your `date_product` initialization.